# htaccess - Redirect one folder to another internally

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect all no-files and no-directories of one folder to another. The .htaccess should be on root (http://example.com).

Example:

```
http://example.com/admin/core/file.php - Does not exists. So, redirect (internally) to http://example.com/adminhide/core/file.php

http://example.com/admin/index.php - Exists. So, don't do anything..
```

I tried to create the code, but I'm having an 500 Internal Server Error:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /adminhide/$1 [L]
```